# Android Adapter implementation

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I'm new to Android. One issue that I'm struggling with is the ArrayAdapter implementation. Read so many tutorials and need to make sure I understand it correctly.

Here is how far I got trying to figure it out:

```
    package hfad.com.adapters;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //thorntech.com parsing jsonandroid using colley library
    TextView results;
    // URL of object to be parsed
    String JsonURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ianbar20/JSON-Volley-Tutorial/master/Example-JSON-Files/Example-Array.JSON";
    // This string will hold the results
    String data = "";
    // Defining the Volley request queue that handles the URL request concurrently

    ListView myList;

    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    //Adding adapter and assign it -set- to a listview



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Creates the Volley request queue
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Casts results into the TextView found within the main layout XML with id jsonData
        results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
        final ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        // Creating the JsonArrayRequest class called arrayreq, passing the required parameters
        //JsonURL is the URL to be fetched from
        JsonArrayRequest arrayreq = new JsonArrayRequest(JsonURL,
                // The second parameter Listener overrides the method onResponse() and passes
                //JSONArray as a parameter
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    // Takes the response from the JSON request
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


     /*        ==================================================================   */
/*  //////////////////////// Example using TextView and it works//////////////////////  */
                        //url https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2
                        try {
                            // Retrieves first JSON object in outer array
                            JSONObject colorObj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            // Retrieves "colorArray" from the JSON object
                            JSONArray colorArry = colorObj.getJSONArray("colorArray");
                            // Iterates through the JSON Array getting objects and adding them
                            //to the list view until there are no more objects in colorArray
                            for (int i = 0; i < colorArry.length(); i++) {
                                //gets each JSON object within the JSON array
                                JSONObject jsonObject = colorArry.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Retrieves the string labeled "colorName" and "hexValue",
                                // and converts them into javascript objects
                                String color = jsonObject.getString("colorName");
                                String hex = jsonObject.getString("hexValue");

                                // Adds strings from the current object to the data string
                                //spacing is included at the end to separate the results from
                                //one another
                                data += "\n"+ "Color Number " + (i + 1) + "\n"+"Color Name: " + color +
                                        "\n"+ "nHex Value : " + hex + "nnn"+ "\n";

                            }
                            // Adds the data string to the TextView "results"
                            results.setText(data);

                        }



/*    ============================================================  */
/* ////////////////////////// Example 2 working ///////////////////////////////   */
                        //url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ianbar20/JSON-Volley-Tutorial/master/Example-JSON-Files/Example-Array.JSON
                       /*
                       try {
                           // Retrieves first JSON object in outer array
                           JSONObject colorObj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                           // Retrieves "colorArray" from the JSON object
                           JSONArray colorArry = colorObj.getJSONArray("colorArray");
                           // Iterates through the JSON Array getting objects and adding them
                           //to the list view until there are no more objects in colorArray
                           for (int i = 0; i < colorArry.length(); i++) {
                               //gets each JSON object within the JSON array
                               JSONObject jsonObject = colorArry.getJSONObject(i);

                               // Retrieves the string labeled "colorName" and "hexValue",
                               // and converts them into javascript objects
                               String color = jsonObject.getString("colorName");
                               String hex = jsonObject.getString("hexValue");

                               // Adds strings from the current object to the data string
                               //spacing is included at the end to separate the results from
                               //one another
                               data += "\n"+ "Color Number " + (i + 1) + "\n"+"Color Name: " + color +
                                      "\n"+ "nHex Value : " + hex + "nnn"+ "\n";
                           }
                           // Adds the data string to the TextView "results"
                           results.setText(data);
                       }

                       */
                        // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
                //as a parameter
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }

        );
        // Adds the JSON array request "arrayreq" to the request queue
        requestQueue.add(arrayreq);
        }}
```

My view has a textview and listview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listv"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="89dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

So how I display my volley response in the listview not the textview (which displays the response as expected) 
Is having a textview and listview in the same view considered wrong?
If I do this: myAdapter.add(results), the app crashes. You say I don't need anything else except getting the list and set the adapter to that list.

Comment: If you are using  ArrayAdapter for populating the listview , you don't have to write any code.  There is a default implementation available in this class.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help me. I updated the code above with something simple I'm trying. How to display the volley response in the listview using the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you understood the main function of the `Adapters` very well. Let me explain to you:

The `ArrayAdapter` class is an `Adapter` (which extends from `BaseAdapter`) that works with `Arrays` and `Lists` and is ready for you to use it without having to call the `getView()` method manually. For it to work you need to pass 3 parameters during its creation:

1 - Your `context`

2 - The `Layout` of each line of the list

3 - Your data in `List` or `Array` formats

**Eg.**

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, items);
```

In this case, the `Android` itself will check the size of your list, get all your data and enter them within each line of your views and return to you in list form.

The `getView()` method that you are worried about belongs to the `ArrayAdapter` superclass (`BaseAdapter`) and it is automatically managed by the app, so do not worry about it. Remember to check if your list is not empty or null before passing it to your adapter.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for helping.  Please take a look at my updated code. I added volley, I get the api, response, loop, then display it in the textview and it works. Now, how to add it to the list view? using myAdapter.add(results? data? add the object) how to get the volley response to display in the listview?

Comment: this is another question, you have to accept this one and ask it in other question. thanks .